# Error "main.exe has stopped working" while trying to run the program

Tags: c++

I am a beginner c++ coder and still learning the basics.

I am writing a program which tests if the inputted number is a perfect number, but whenever I run the code I get an error saying main.exe has stopped working.

I've also reviewed similar questions asked on this site but I didn't understand.

Can someone explain it very simply?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, number, s = 0;
    cin >> umber;

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
        if (number % i == 0)
            s += i;

    if (number == s)
       cout << "the umber is perfect";
    else
       cout << "the number is not perfect";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The modulo operator `%` performs a division. Now think about what happens when `i` is zero and you try to do a division by zero...

Comment: @Someprogrammeare so what you are trying to say is that if division with 0 never happens i won't get that error?

Comment: yeah, just set i to 1 instead of 0

Comment: cin>>umber;   ->    cin>>number;

Comment: Run the program under a debugger. It will show you the exact line at which the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, aside from inputting to an undefined variable on line 6

```
cin>>umber;
```

which you should change to:

```
cin>>number;
```

you have a floating point exception happening, you are performing a modulo operation on a loop index (i) that starts from zero:

```
for (i=0;i<number;i++)
   if(number%i==0)
```

a modulo operation is similar to division, and just like you can't divide by zero, you can't do modulo zero.